# How to read local temporary table's rows/record which is used in stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a long, legacy stored procedure where local temporary table is first loaded with set of records and then this local temporary table is updated many times in the stored procedure with different update statements step by step.

I want to check the records of temporary table every time it is updated. Please suggest, how to read intermediate result of local temporary table.

I can modify the stored procedure temporarily.

Comment: Just `Select * from #tempTable`, inside your stored procedure, after every update statement.

Comment: This SP is called from asp.net web application which is hosted. Everytime parameter value changes that is passing to SP and difficult to know exact value of each parameters.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with your question or my response.

Comment: An alternative to selecting rows for immediate visual consumption while the procedure is executing in SSMS is to create a permanent table and insert the rows from the temp table as needed (with some sort of identifier to know the associated code location). But the short answer is nothing can directly access a local temp table created within a procedure.

Comment: Are you asking how to know the parameters or how to read the temp table? And by reading the temp table, do you mean reading from other process like SSMS?

Comment: We can use SQL Profiler to capture the sp trace along with parameters, so that, we can use the same independent of the asp.net application for debugging or understanding purposes by adding select statements as suggested by @RBarryYoung.

Answer (score 3):

Using

```sql
select * from #yourTempTable
```

will give you the results.

Furthermore, if you want to access `#yourTempTable` in the `tempdb`, you can do so by using:

```sql
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#yourTempTable') is not null
```